# Trying to a build a map from sensor data (Gmapping)

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using ROS Kinetic and I am trying to use a hokuyo laser sensor to a build a map from. I have seen the [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) package, but I have some questions regarding this. As I understand:

1. I will use the messages (Type: sensor_msgs/LaserScan) from the /my_robot/laser/scan topic.
2. I need to use the [required tf](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping#Required_tf_Transforms) for that. Could someone explain to me what does this mean ? Should I add the tf at my URDF code or follow this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials)?
3. After that I will `rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping` and from the data I will get from the sensor, I will build a map at  nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid .
4. I will visualize the map on rviz, after adding by topic /map.

Have I understood correctly the sequence of steps I need to follow to complete the building of the map or I am missing something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240505/trying-to-a-build-a-map-from-sensor-data-(gmapping)/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [angryhippo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28103/angryhippo/) on 2016-09-28**:
What did you use to as a driver for your laser? I used urg_node on ros indigo but that package is not available yet on kinetic?

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-09-28**:
I wasn't using the actual sensor when I did the question, but a urdf model of the sensor.
Now I am using the rplidar, which has a relevant package regarding the driver of the sensor.
For your case, I would suggest trying to find a node for your sensor type.

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-09-28**:
I cannot help you further, because in real life I am not using a hokuyo sensor, but if you search it, I don't believe you will meet an issue about the driver.

Good luck !:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

More or less. Gmapping subscribes to the /scan topic, so you will need to remap /my_robot/laser/scan to /scan or vice versa.

For the tf, you need a transform from the laser sensor to the robot base. You can add the sensor to the URDF model if you want a visualization of it in RVIZ or you can use a static transform publisher.

Gmapping requires an odometry source. You don't state if you have one or not so I figured I would just point it out.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-07-28**:
My frames from the frames_viewer can be seen [here](https://postimg.org/image/un04gk0kx/) .As you can see my tf tree consists of only /odom->/base_footprint So I would need this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF) to continue with the static transform publisher ?

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-07-28**:
You can follow that tutorial if you want to build your own transform broadcaster. As you only need a single link for this at the moment, you can also use the [tf static_transform_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher)